# clustering a set of rectangles

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, cluster-analysis

I have a set of rectangles which I need to cluster together, based on euclidean distance between them.The situation is explained in the attached image. [image: The situation is explained in the attached image].

One possible approach is to take the center of each rectangle and cluster the center points using K means (distance function would be euclidean distance in XY plane). However, I would like to know if there is any other approach to this problem, which does not approximate a rectangle by it's central point, but also takes the actual shape of the rectangle into consideration.

Comment: http://uclue.com/?xq=4737
This thread could be useful for You. It is about to find the shortest distance between two rectangles.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at algorithms such as [DBSCAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) and [OPTICS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPTICS) that can be used with arbitrary data types as long as you can define a distance between them (such as the minimum rectangle-to-rectangle distance).

K-means is probably not so good, as it is designed for point data with squared euclidean distance (= sum of squares, within-cluster-variance).

Answer (score 2):

One way to formulate this problem is to look at each rectangle `i`, and each pair of rectangles `(i,j)` having distance `d(i,j)`, and then forming a distance matrix from those. This distance measure `d` could be distance between rectangle centers *or* something more fancy like distance between closest points on rectangles.

Then, apply a clustering algorithm that takes a distance matrix as input, where you define your distance matrix `D` as the matrix where element `(i,j)` is `d(i,j)`.

Related: [Clustering with a distance matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725170/clustering-with-a-distance-matrix)

Anony-Mousse's answer has some nice suggestions for algorithms you could use to cluster given the distance matrix.

Answer (score 1):

We used [Spectral Clustering](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering.html) with left_x, right_x, top_y, bottom_y coordinates as features with pretty good results.